# link to association rails No such column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I am trying to set up a search function in Rails. I have a table called documents. I can search on the subject and the text in the body. Where I am having an issue is trying to to search on fields in associated tables. I have a table called authors. I want to be able to put a name in the author field and return the documents matching that author.

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :documents

  def search_documents

    documents = Document.all

    documents = documents.where("subject like ?", "%#{subject}%") if subject.present?
    documents = documents.where("body like ?", "%#{text}%") if text.present?
    documents = documents.author.where("author like ?", "%#{author}%") if author.present?

    return documents
  end

end
```

The subject and body works fine. I've tried all kinds of variations on the author line with no luck . The schema for my documents model looks as follows with author_id linking to the authors table on a has_many relationship between docs and authors

```
create_table "documents", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "subject"
  t.text     "body"
  t.integer  "category_id"
  t.integer  "tag_id"
  t.integer  "author_id"
  t.integer  "reviewer_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",                       null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                       null: false
  t.string   "document_attachment_file_name"
  t.string   "document_attachment_content_type"
  t.integer  "document_attachment_file_size"
  t.datetime "document_attachment_updated_at"
  t.integer  "attached_files_id"
  t.string   "token"
end
```

Is there a way to reference the author's name in

```
documents.author.where("author like ?", "%#{author}%") if author.present?
```

Right now, I am getting an error as follows

> Showing C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/Rl2/app/views/searches/show.html.erb where line #9 raised:
>   undefined method `author' for #<Document::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xa20a0f8>
>   Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/Rl2
>   Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/models/search.rb:12:in`search_documents'
>   app/views/searches/show.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_searches_show_html_erb__631448441_64839156'

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
documents.joins(:author).where("authors.name like ?", "%#{author}%") if author.present?
```

This assumes that the name of the author is stored in a column called `name` in the `authors` table and the `Document` model has a `belongs_to :author`.